# Simplifying Rounding code C

Tags: c, rounding

I'm new to coding and trying to figure out how to get code to round up to the next hour. The only method I've been able to think up (i.e. the only method I've been taught) is to just make else if statements for every hour. Clearly this isn't efficient at all and i know there's probably something much simpler. I was given a clue that there's a math equation involved?

Here's what i coded up so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
//listens for value of "cost"
    float cost;
    printf("How much does this go-kart location charge per hour?\n");
    scanf("%f", &cost);
//listens for value of "time"
    float time;
    printf("How many minutes can you spend there?\n");
    scanf("%f", &time);
// i have to get it to round time to values of 60 (round up to next hour)
//really overcomplicated lack of knowledge workaround.txt
    if (time < 60 && time > 0){
    time = 1;
   } else if(time > 61 && time < 70){
    time = 2;
   } else if(time > 71 && time < 80){
    time = 3;
   } else if(time > 81 && time < 90){
    time = 4;
   } else if(time > 91 && time < 100){
    time = 5;
   } else if(time > 101 && time < 160){
    time = 6;
   }
//etc etc

float total = cost * time;

printf("Your total will be $%f\n", total);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `numHours = mins / 60`

Comment: @FiddlingBits yes but it wont work if the answer is something like 75 minutes. The equation will equal 1.25 and it'll round down. I need it to round up to the next hour

Comment: Why are you using `float` for the minutes? Is this intentional to support seconds? If not then I would just use `int`. Otherwise if you need to use float then you can do `ceil(time / 60)`, see [http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/ceil](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/ceil) (it's in <math.h>).

Answer (score 2):

For non regular intervals, one could do something like

```
int times[] = { 60; 70; 80; 90; 100; 160; INT_MAX }; // INT_MAX is to avoid segfault for bad input
int facts[] = {  1;  2;  3;  4;   5;   6;      -1 }; // -1 is value for bad input

int it = 0;
while(times[it] < time) ++it;

int result = facts[it];
```

Note that you code doesnt have valid results for time = 60, 70, etc ... you should check the wanted behaviour

Answer (score 1):

```
int hour = time/60;

if(60*hour < time)
  ++hour;
```

Comment: @FiddlingBits: arguable, and at the cost of introducing another operation. I thought of mentioning `ceil`, but that isn't really the kind of help the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly basic math.

`time` / 60 would round down to to give you the hour.

Therefore (`time` / 60) + 1 rounds up.

If the maximum is 6 hours then simply check:

```
hour = time/60 + 1;
if (hour > 6) hour = 6;
```

Of course I'm assuming that time is an `int`. If it's a `float` then you can use `floor` or `ceil` to round up or down:

```
hour = floor(time/60 +1);
```

or

```
hour = ceil(time/60);
```

Comment: didn't know about the +1. Thank you! The Float in front of time was messing things up too. Last code i did, i had to set everything as a float (despite some things being integers) for it to work. Still unsure why it breaks things sometimes and fixes things other times. I'll figure things out eventually. Thanks again!

Comment: @snazz I'm used to working on all ints (it's an embedded programmer thing). So I didn't realize that the example code used float. Be sure to understand what floats really are and how type promotion/coercion works. That's good advice in any language but is especially more so in C.

Comment: "(time / 60) + 1 rounds up" would take `time` with a value of 60 minutes and return 2 hours.  I would expect rounding up or rounding down 60 minutes should both result in 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not bad

```
time = (time % 60) ? time / 60 + 1 : time / 60
```

Comment: As written a `float` is being used for time.

Comment: sorry i didn't see that, then  `time = ceilf(time / 60)` should work. another way is first cast it and then use above code.